# Check and return value using span tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a dropdownlist that I want to wrap in a span.
What I would like to happen is...

When a user selects a new item from the dropdownlist, the span will check a js function and accept a return value of true/false.

If the span value = true then let the user continue with the selection, otherwise cancel selection and return the dropdownlist selected value to -1.

I have looked at many examples for the span tag but haven't been able to find something that will return a value.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks

```
 <span ????>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSelectFormula" runat="server" 
           AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="controltext" 
           DataSourceID="lnqSelectFormula" DataTextField="FormulaName" 
           DataValueField="FormulaID">
           <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select Formula" Value="-1">   </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
 </span>
```

---

```
 function checkFormulaID() {
    var hi = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiFormulaIDList").value;
    var dd = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddSelectClientFormula").value;
    var ddVal = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
    if (hi > 0 && ddVal > 0) {
        var retVal = confirm("Do you want to replace the current formula with this one?");
        if (retVal == true) {
            return true;
        };
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need a span.

Comment: I only want to do a postback if I have to.  I have wrapped delete buttons with a span and have been able to get a response, so I thought if I could wrap one around a dropdown I could do something similar. 
Basically, if there is a value in the hiddenfield and the user wants to change the value then I have to do some stuff in code behind, but if the user doesn't want to then I don't have to go into code behind.
I hope this makes since.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your OP did not refer to any hidden field, so I am not sure how that comes in to the formula. Sounds like you just want to implement a 'dirty' check. If the value changes, then stuff that value in the hidden field. That is pretty easy to accomplish. Let us know more detail in what you are trying to accomplish. It sounds one way, but may be something else...

Comment: The var hi is the hidden field.  So if the value > 0 then there is already a formula and need to delete and refill the nested grids, if user wants to change formulas, otherwise I don't want the code behind event to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdownlist just needs to include

```
    OnClientClick="checkFormulaID"
```

You may also have to edit your JS for the comparison if (hi > 0 && ddVal > 0) since JS can do crazy things with the value propery.